# Await for value in Promise before executing API - Error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

Tags: ionic3, typescript2.0

I'm trying to generate and hash a value which will be used in an API Post. But API is always executing with an `undefined` value. So i decided to use the `Promise` function to `await` value and then temporarily save it so i can use it with the API.

```
async HashValue(){

var generateValue = PasswordGenerator.generate({length: 25});

const HashPBKDF2value = (getGenValue) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve();
    });
  };

MosquittoPBKDF.createPasswordAsync(generateValue,HashPBKDF2value);

let hashedValue = await HashPBKDF2value();
console.log("Hashed Value", hashedValue);
this.storage.set("ValueHashed", hashedValue);

 if (hashedValue) {
 this.RunAPI();
 }

}

RunAPI() {
// Get stored hashedValue
// API runs here
}
```

I'm getting an Error:

```
 Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. 

 let hashedValue = await HashPBKDF2value();
 console.log("Hashed Value", hashedValue);
```

I can't seem to figure out the argument needed `HashPBKDF2value(Argument);`

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix, I changed

```
let hashedValue = await HashPBKDF2value();
```

to

```
let hashedValue = await HashPBKDF2value;
```